# php array iteration over multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have 4 arrays listed below .can any one tell me how to print 0 and 3rd index values of each array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7406072674
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => Dear Student,  FlipTutor has credited 10 FREE coins. Connect with expert teacher and clear your doubts. Install App - http://bit.ly/1WIaNKD
    [4] => 139
    [5] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 7676731030
    [1] => hkjhk
    [2] => hgk
    [3] => Dear Nishant, FlipTutor has credited 10 FREE coins. Connect with expert teacher and clear your doubts. Install App - http://bit.ly/1WIaNKD
    [4] => 138
    [5] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9738040711
    [1] => ljlhkhjk
    [2] => khgkj
    [3] => Dear Sonu, FlipTutor has credited 10 FREE coins. Connect with expert teacher and clear your doubts. Install App - http://bit.ly/1WIaNKD
    [4] => 135
    [5] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9949942011
    [1] => anil
    [2] => sdfsd
    [3] => Dear Anil, FlipTutor has credited 10 FREE coins. Connect with expert teacher and clear your doubts. Install App - http://bit.ly/1WIaNKD
    [4] => 123
    [5] => 1
)
```

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal? Also what is the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for you reply i want to print each array [0] and [3] index values.

Comment: Please include the relevant information in your question like, do you want for each array: `[0][3][0][3]...` or first all `[0]` and then all `[3]` ? Also include your current attempt into your question.

Comment: You should attempt to do this yourself and then come back when you run into issues :) look into `foreach`. Loop through each array, and then print the 0 and 3 indexes. This should give you multiple `foreach` loops, however. You can then extract this to a function containing just one foreach loop, and pass the arrays to it as the value to loop through.

Comment: i want for each array: [0][3][0][3]. values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrays = "YOUR 4 ARRAYS";

foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $newArray[]=$array[0];
    $newArray[]=$array[3];
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: `E_WARNING : type 2 -- Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. Jk, of course...

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.